# Hibernate AttributeOverride is not working

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations

I have a child class that overrides the getter (because it adds a different behavior) of its super class. I am using @AttributeOverride but it's throws the error **org.hibernate.MappingException: Duplicate property mapping of name found in com.hbmap.domain.Product** too.

I am not sure if i am doing something wrong.

**Product:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
@AttributeOverride(name = "name", column = @Column(name = "name") )
public class Product extends Properties {

  private Long id;

  @Id
  @Column(name = "id")
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  public Long getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  @Override
  public String getName() {
    // Do something different than superclass
    return super.getName();
  }
}
```

**Properties (super class):**

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
public class Properties {
  private String name;

  @Column(name="name")
  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}
```

**Edited 1**

**Full stacktrace:**

> org.hibernate.MappingException: Duplicate property mapping of name found in com.hbmap.domain.Product
>       at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkPropertyDuplication(PersistentClass.java:515)
>       at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:505)
>       at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:270)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validate(Configuration.java:1360)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1851)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1930)
>       at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:372)
>       at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:454)
>       at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:439)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1633)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:663)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:629)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:677)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:548)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:489)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
>       at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1231)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1144)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1031)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4914)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5201)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1399)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: Can you please show full stack trace?

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution, I don't know if it's the best, but it works....
Add **@Transient** to getter in the subclass.

**Product:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
@AttributeOverride(name = "name", column = @Column(name = "name") )
public class Product extends Properties {

  private Long id;

  @Id
  @Column(name = "id")
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  public Long getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  @Override
  @Transient
  public String getName() {
    // Do something different than superclass
    return super.getName();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are overridng `getName()` method in your `Product` class, which will reuse the `@Column` annotation twice and that will try to create two Columns for `name`.

That's why you got the EXception:

> org.hibernate.MappingException: Duplicate property mapping of name found in com.hbmap.domain.Product

So simply remove the Overriden method from your `Product` class because it will automatically get the name from the super class because `Inheritance` will do it for you, Remove this :

```
@Override
public String getName() {
  return super.getName();
}
```

**EDIT:**

In case you need to override it, using `@Transient` with the overriden method will skip this new Column in mapping.

Comment: I need to override the method because in the subclass I am adding a diferent behavior.

Comment: In that case `@Transient` is what you need, because it will ignore this column in mapping, or maybe if you try to remove the `@Column` from the method in the super class and ad it to the overriden one.

Comment: Yes I did that, it seems to be the only solution. Thanks !